# wifi problem on ubuntu 20.04 after upgrade

Tags: server, wireless, upgrade, updates

I installed ubuntu LTS 20.04 server on Raspberry 4 Model B and I tested the wifi it works well,but when i upgraded ubuntu the wifi is not working after this upgrade, Have you any idea about this problem?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check the `journalctl -e | grep NetworkManager`? That's where the service writes logs to.

Comment: Nothing appears

Comment: run `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` or try `systemctl start NetworkManager.service` and see if it works

Comment: Failed to start NetworkManager.service ,Unit NetworkManager not found

Comment: Ok you could try installing a file, but before that try rebooting pc, and running the command I wrote again

Comment: yep. I rebooted Raspberry Pi  and I executed the commands you wrote but not working

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

- `ls /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service`

**double check that the output it's not found**

- If the file is not there, add the service unit back

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Manager
Documentation=man:NetworkManager(8)
Wants=network.target
After=network-pre.target dbus.service
Before=network.target 

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager
ExecReload=/usr/bin/busctl call org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager Reload u 0
#ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
Restart=on-failure
# NM doesn't want systemd to kill its children for it
KillMode=process
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_MODULE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE CAP_KILL CAP_SYS_CHROOT

ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=read-only

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Also=NetworkManager-dispatcher.service

# We want to enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service whenever this service
# is enabled. NetworkManager-wait-online.service has
# WantedBy=network-online.target, so enabling it only has an effect if
# network-online.target itself is enabled or pulled in by some other unit.
Also=NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Save into `NetworkManager.service`

- Run `sudo mv NetworkManager.service /lib/systemd/system/`
- start the service using `systemctl start NetworkManager.service`

Then update and upgrade.

Comment: I created the file NetworkManager in the /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service and and I did what you wrote sir but don't worked with me

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: here is the output of the 2 commands    :ubuntu@ubuntu:/lib/systemd/system$ sudo mv NetworkManager.service /lib/systemd/system/
mv: 'NetworkManager.service' and '/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service' are the same file
ubuntu@ubuntu:/lib/systemd/system$ systemctl start NetworkManager.service
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: It's telling you to run `journalctl -xe` after the last command